# Hide URL calls from HTML block

Tags: urls

I'm plotting some real-time data in my website using the Apexcharts library and a widget from Tradingview, using HTML blocks in wordpress. I'm fecthing the data from a raw url in my github page but it's obviously visible to anyone who views the source code.

I wish to hide the data source in my website but I'm struggling on how to do it since I'm a beginner at wordpress and html in general.

I've heard about some ideas such as using environment variables or using private github repo's but I always end up not knowing how to use wordpress to do this.

Am I overcomplicating this or is there any simple way to hide this the information?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Broadly, you can't: if the client needs to call an API from your user's browser then you'll need to send the details over to the client. You could e.g. proxy the data through an API on your website instead, and enforce access control there, and with a reasonable cache that might not add too much server load. You can also try and add defences on the API server end e.g. try and detect if you're being called from something other than a browser, or something other than by your website, and you can include temporary access tokens or signed requests there too etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understood some of the things you said but, for access control in particular, you're saying that I can restrict the API call to my website only? How could I do that from a simple HTML block in wordpress?

Comment: You can’t. You would need to create an API that sites between your website and the GitHub URL and performs the access controls. This is all stuff that needs to happen completely outside WordPress.

Comment: I actually have a server which I could use for this purpose. Could you highlight how this could be achieved? Thanks!